# Bar construction and the $\infty$-categorical Barr-Beck theorem

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

I am studying the proof of the $\infty$-categorical version of the Barr-Beck theorem in Lurie's Higher Algebra, but there is a step of the proof that is puzzling me. In Lemma 4.7.3.13, a simplicial object $M_{\bullet}$ in the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{LMod}_T(\mathcal C)$ is constucted as $\operatorname{Bar}_T(T,M)_{\bullet}$.

My question is: what are the correct choices of $\mathcal C^{\otimes}$, $F_0$ and $f$ in Construction 4.4.2.7 in order to obtain the $\operatorname{Bar}_T(T,M)_{\bullet}$ used in the proof of Lemma 4.7.3.13?

As far as I understand, the idea is to apply the bar construction (Construction 4.4.2.7), to the coCartesian fibration of $\infty$-operads $\mathcal A^{\otimes} \to \mathcal{LM}^{\otimes}$ (here I am using $\mathcal A$ instead of $\mathcal C$ to avoid the conflict of notation with the $\mathcal C$ of Lemma 4.7.3.13) expressing $\mathcal C$ as weakly enriched over $\mathrm{End}(\mathcal C)^{\otimes}$ (that is, with $\mathcal A^{\otimes}_{\mathfrak m} \simeq \mathcal C$ and $\mathcal A^{\otimes}_{\mathfrak a} \simeq \mathrm{End}(\mathcal C)^{\otimes}$). My problem is now how to define $F_0$ and $f$ (with the notations of Construction 4.4.2.7) in order to get $\operatorname{Bar}_T(T,M)_{\bullet}$, and even how to make sense of the "bimodule instance" of $T$ in that expression.
To be more precise, $F_0$ should determine two bimodules in $\mathcal C$, but since $\mathcal C$ is only left tensored over $\mathrm{End}(\mathcal C)^{\otimes}$, I don't know how to make sense of the construction (in fact, I don't know how to make sense of the construction for any base $\infty$-operad other than $\mathcal O^{\otimes} = \mathcal{BM}^{\otimes}$). Moreover, even interpreting $M$ as some sort of bimodule (maybe with some kind of trivial right action, but I am just guessing), I can't find a way to interpret the second instance of $T$ in the expression $\operatorname{Bar}_T(T,M)_{\bullet}$. Or maybe I am just considering the wrong coCartesian fibration of $\infty$-operads to begin with, but then I have no clue about any other possible option.

Comment: I would guess that the relevant input is $\mathcal A^\otimes \to \mathcal{BM}^\otimes$ encoding $\mathcal C$ as left tensored over $End(\mathcal C)$ and right tensored over $*$, the map $f$ being the retraction discussed in Example 4.4.2.12.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Yes, this definitely works, thank you. If you add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @StefanoAriotta Dear Stefano, did you manage to figure out more about the Bar construction used in this proof? I'm interested to know if you understand the fact that it is claimed to be a simplicial object in the category $\mathrm{LMod}_T(\mathcal{C})$ and not just in the underlying category $\mathcal{C}$ like in construction 4.4.2.7.